# synchronize two thread category

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to develop an application where there are two thread category: A thread and the thread B.
 if thread A is in the critical section, the thread B must wait until all thread A finish.
 and if the thread B are in the critical section, the thread A must wait until all thread A complete

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplicationPontAVoieUnique
{
class Program
{
    public static int nbrA=0;
    public static int nbrB = 0;

    public static Semaphore semA;
    public static Semaphore semB;
    public static Semaphore semNbrA;
    public static Semaphore semNbrB;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        semNbrA = new Semaphore(1, 2);
        semNbrB = new Semaphore(1, 2);

        semA = new Semaphore(0, 3);
        semB = new Semaphore(0, 3);


        Thread A1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ActionThreadA));
        A1.IsBackground = true;
        A1.Name = "A1";
        A1.Start();

        Thread B1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ActionThreadB));
        B1.IsBackground = true;
        B1.Name = "B1";
        B1.Start();

         Thread A2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ActionThreadA));
        A2.IsBackground = true;
        A2.Name = "A2";
        A2.Start();

        Thread B2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ActionThreadB));
        B2.IsBackground = true;
        B2.Name = "B2";
        B2.Start();

        Thread A3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ActionThreadA));
        A3.IsBackground = true;
        A3.Name = "A3";
        A3.Start();

        Thread B3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ActionThreadB));
        B3.IsBackground = true;
        B3.Name = "B3";
        B3.Start();

        Thread A4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ActionThreadA));
        A4.IsBackground = true;
        A4.Name = "A4";
        A4.Start();

        Thread B4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ActionThreadB));
        B4.IsBackground = true;
        B4.Name = "B4";
        B4.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ActionThreadA()
    {
        semNbrA.WaitOne();

        nbrA++;
        if (nbrA == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " I'am the first A ");
            semB.WaitOne();
        }
        semNbrA.Release();

        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " I'am in the cs ");

        Thread.Sleep(5000); //sc

        semNbrA.WaitOne();

        nbrA--;
        if (nbrA == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " I'am the last A ");
            semB.Release();
        }
        semNbrA.Release();


    }
    static void ActionThreadB()
    {
        semNbrB.WaitOne();

        nbrB++;
        if (nbrB == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " I'am the first B ");
            semA.WaitOne();
        }
        semNbrB.Release();

        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " I'am in the cs ");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        semNbrB.WaitOne();

        nbrB--;
        if (nbrB == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " I'am the last B ");
            semA.Release();
        }
        semNbrB.Release();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What's the question?
You can use lock [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) and [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Semaphores.

Comment: how to use AutoResetEvent?

Comment: i think it's a good illustration: http://multithreads.blogspot.ru/2007/09/eventwaithandler-autoresetevent-and.html